# Build folder stays empty

Tags: eclipse, struts2

Hi Im trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27) regarding Struts. I have followed the tutorial exactly but am getting an HTTP 404 error. I know this error basically means that the resource can't be found be the the IDE.

I noticed that the 'Build' folder is actually completely empty - so I'm guessing that it should have automatically created a runnable project based on my project specifics and this is actually where the server looks in order to run an application.

So how do I go about manually generating this file? Should I drag all the resources in? Java classes, JSP files and so? If not how do I configure it to automatically build?

Cheers

**EDIT**

Have added what I think will be necessary to help solve this:

**Web.xml** Located in the WEB-INF folder, next to lib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**Struts.xml** Located in a src folder called resources in the Java Resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

<!-- 
     If we changed from the default execute() method, which struts looks for
     to say authenticate(), then we would have to specify this in the action 
     method below like this:

     <action 
             name="login" 
             method="authenticate" 
             class="net.viralpatel.struts2.LoginAction">
     </action>

-->
    <action name="login" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.LoginAction">

        <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>

    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Not enough info to help.

Comment: Anything--manually generating *what* file? Drag all resources... from where? What are the resources you're talking about? What version of S2 are you targeting? What's in the console log on startup? Are you in devMode? Have you turned logging up to DEBUG level? Etc. Also, that's a pretty old version of S2.

Comment: FWIW, at first glance the tutorial seems correct.

Comment: Is the resources folder marked as a source folder? Can you not turn on devMode and turn up logging?

Comment: How do you do that? How can that be an old version of Struts 2? I got the zip folder from the Apache site "19 November 2012 - Struts 2.3.7 General Availability Release"

Comment: How can that be an old version of Struts? The tutorial is almost three years old. You didn't specify what version you're using. You're following directions for version 2.0, and now you say you're using 2.3, which is different, and I can't see over your shoulder to magically know what version you're using. That's how.

Comment: I thought you meant the version of struts I was using

Comment: ... I did, and everything I said addresses why I thought that.